# Grep in files with a specific extension under a directory

Tags: terminal, search, grep

Is there a command that allows searching a keyword in files under a directory with specific extension ?

The string `grep -irn "string" ./path` gives a recursive search for all files under the directory`./path`. My specific requirement is to search in all files under `./path` with an extension such as `*.h`

Answer (score 11):

After some trials, I think `grep -irn 'string' --include '*.h'` is more handy

Comment: If you're going to do that, be sure to put the `"*.h"` in quotes.

Comment: It works with and without quotes

Comment: Now it does. Try creating a file called `foobar.h` in the current directory, and try it again.

Answer (score 10):

**S**et (turn on) the **sh**ell **opt**ion `globstar` with the command

```
    shopt -s globstar
```

This will cause `**` as a filename component to mean
everything here and below. 
So `path/**` means everything in the `path` directory
*and its subdirectories*. 
(You don't need to type `./` here.) 
Then you can use

```
grep -in "string" path/**/*.h
```

to search all the `.h` files in and under `path`.

---

You can **u**nset options with `shopt -u`.

Answer (score 5):

```
find /path -iname "*.h" -exec grep -inH "string" "{}" \;
```

Comment: `-exec` ... `+` is good, too.

Comment: I just noticed — you forgot to include `"string"` in your answer!

Answer (score 3):

If you can install something on your machine, I suggest using [ack](http://beyondgrep.com/).

You can do exactly what you need with it and much more.
For your use case, you can do:

```
# Depending of your system, you have to use one or the other
ack --hh -i string path
ack-grep --hh -i string path
```

- **--hh** filters on *h* files
- **-i** ignores the case

To find which file filters are supported natively, run the command `ack --help=type`.

Comment: There's also [ag](http://geoff.greer.fm/ag/), a former clone of ack. Former, because their feature sets have since diverged somewhat.

Comment: I didn't know ag. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 3):

What about this one?

```
find -L ./path -name "*.h" -exec grep -in "string" {} \;
```

Explanation:

- -L : follow symlinks
- -name : using the asterisk, you can describe extensions
- -in : same as your proposal, but the 'r' is replaced by the `find` command
- {} : this stands for the result of the `find` command
- \; : in case you combine `find` with `-exec`, this is the end-of-command specifier

Comment: How does `"*.h"` work? I would have thought it needed to be `'*.h'`

Comment: I always work with double quotes, I don't think it makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using gnu grep then it's got a flag that does exactly what you want:

```
grep -irn --include=\*.h "string" path
```

although I don't think it's available in other greps.